# PHP Levenshtein distance

Tags: php, levenshtein-distance

I want to display **Did you mean** alternative when user searches for incorrect word. This code works, but some results are irrelevant. Example: I have an **apple** record in my table. If user searches for **apple1** result is: Did you mean **apple?**, but if user searches for **aple** result is: Did you mean **Dole**? Is there any way to display more relevant results? Here is a code:

```
$search = $_GET ['search'];

$results = array();
foreach ($db->query("SELECT id FROM table") as $name) {
$results[] = $name['id'];
}

$shortest = -1;
foreach ($results as $word) {
$lev = levenshtein($search, $word);

if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
    $closest  = $word;
    $shortest = $lev;
}
}
echo $closest;
```

Comment: you might want to use http://php.net/soundex instead. On a side note, the levenshtein distance between apple and apple is 1 and 2 between Dole and aple, so I am not sure why your code gives you that result.

Comment: I just ran your code and I got **apple**. Maybe there's something wrong in your `$result` array or with your `$search` string?

Comment: And be aware that your code will return the last match if there is more than one result with the lowest Levenshtein distance. So if you have apple and somewhere later maple in your results (both with a Levenshtein distance of 1 for $search = "aple";), the return will be maple.

Comment: Thank you for response. I'm thinking about result Dole. I have only these lines and nothing else. Above of this lines are connection details and search form.